# Is there a way to unmask the login password in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, keyboard, dvorak

I use two different keyboard layouts and I never know which one I'm in at the login. The keyboard layout indicator at the login always says USA whether I'm in Qwerty or Programmer Dvorak.

I have no need for the extra security of password masking.

I'm using Natty. I plan on upgrading soon.

Comment: I believe the login prompt allows you to select which keyboard you need, but you might have to choose "Other" for user instead of the default.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the shell switching functionality on the login screen? If not, you could enable automatic login and pass the login screen altogether. See: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/03/automatically-logon-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-typing-passwords/

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to completely remove the password requirement. I was really hoping for a way to remove the masking. I suppose I might just remove Qwerty so that I'm always in Dvorak.

Comment: I understand that my suggestion was not a solution for your query. My point is if you have a readable password entry field, you might want to skip the login screen because anyone could see it as you type. Roughly equivalent to have a sticky note with the password on your monitor.